# Windows / Chrome / ATI / Browser fullscreen across multiple monitors

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen, multiple-monitors, kiosk, chromeless

I am using the following test setup (Latest meaning as of July 14th 2012):

- Core i7 with an ATI FirePro V9800 (Eyefinity)
- Windows 7 Pro 64 Bit (latest updates / patches)
- Latest Catalyst drivers
- Latest Google Chrome Stable / Canary.
- 6 x 1080p displays (in a row) resulting in a **11520px by 1080px desktop**.

I have tried the following to get a fullscreen web view across displays:

- Set the maximize to whole desktop setting in the Catalyst control panel. That works for maximizing normal windows (except Chrome), but not for anything fullscreen.
- Tried Chrome Kiosk mode (that would be ideal), same problem, only fills up primary display.
- Using Chrome Fullscreen or HTML5 fullscreen API results in the same: Fullscreen on a single of the 6 monitors.
- IE9 seems to have a limitation of about 10000px for the webview, thus i cannot even stretch it across the entire desktop manually (that works with Chrome).
- Tried UltraMon.
- Tried a number of Chrome command line switches (http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) for kiosk mode, start in fullscreen etc., so right now using the --app="http://127.0.0.1/index.html" switch to at least get rid of most of Chrome's UI elements.
- Tried to find an extension for Chrome, but no success.
- Tried Chrome Frame in IE9, also only uses one display.

I understand it is most probably a driver issue reporting the wrong desktop size to Chrome (which I thought was the point of the Catalyst Maximize to full desktop size function). Chrome does not seem to get the desktop size from the same place as other "normal" windows do (obviously not very familiar with Windows windowing).

I would like to work on a **full-screen Chrome webview across multiple monitors** or a completely chromeless window that I can manually maximize. My browser configuration is flexible, even the OS is somewhat flexible.

I would like to know:

- Has anyone gotten a fullscreen browser view across more than 1 monitor to work with Chrome (or any browser)?
- Are there any tools that can fake the right (full) display size to Chrome?
- Could this be workable in Windows 8?
- Is there something that just displays a Chromeless Chrome browser that runs the very latest Chrome? (I have seen awesomium, but find that its price is too high for what I want it to do). Also I want to be able to use the most recent Chrome releases ideally.

Any comments welcome and sorry for the lengthy details.

Thanks for reading!
-Tobi

Comment: Hi Tobi,  I think there is a limitation in chrome which prevents this.    Also, you do not have to duplicate the tags (things at the bottom of the post) in the title of the quest.

Comment: well, that's kind of hackish in the first place...if you're working with something simple enough, you might be able to create six `<canvas>`es across windows and paint on them concurrently...

Comment: @Trisped Sorry thought it helps the search ;)

Comment: @gengkev Thanks, unfortunately I would need one big area in my webview. And yes, it is kind of hacky, because of several weird requirements.

Comment: I mean, create six windows and synchronize painting across them...ok, probably not what you're looking for, but I don't know otherwise.

Comment: @gengkev it's a good idea, but sadly because of some libraries that I have to use, it isn't an option in this case. But thanks!!

Comment: libraries? you can have all your logic in one window and gain references to the other five canvases so you can paint on them...okay, okay, whatever :)

Comment: Hehe Yea but I am using a library that basically assumes one giant space. ;-)

Comment: I voted to close this question because it violates several SO rules. SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using two monitors:

start C:\Users\terminal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --app="http://www.domain1.com" --window-position=0,0 --kiosk --user-data-dir=c:/monitor1

start C:\Users\terminal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --app="http://www.domain2.com" --window-position=1680,0 --kiosk --user-data-dir=c:/monitor2

I think the order of the parameters is relevant.